# Scroll view inside another scroll view with different scrolling directions

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, offset, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to design a view similar to this:

[image: iPhone_scrollView]

That is, I have an `UIScrollView` within another `UIScrollView`. The scroll view in light gray is the parent: it occupies the whole screen width and it is intended for vertical scrolling only. The scroll view inside this, the one in dark gray, occupies only part of its parent's width, and it is intended for horizontal scrolling only.

The behaviour I'm trying to achieve is this: I'd like to be able to scroll vertically all the content of the parent scroll view at the same time, including the content in the inner scroll view. But, on the other hand, I'd like to be able to scroll horizontally only the inner scroll view.

I managed to avoid scrolling horizontally the parent scrol view by fiting its content width to the screen, but I'm not able to avoid scrolling vertically the scroll view inside by its own: I want the scroll view inside to scroll vertically only when the whole parent scroll view does.

How could I manage this scenario? Thanks!

**EDIT.** I tried to do this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   if (scrollView == self.childScrollView) {
      [self.parentScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.parentScrollView.contentOffset.x, self.childScrollView.contentOffset.y)];
      [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)];
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do with this is, when dragging the child view controller vertically, scroll its parent view controller, that is supposed to scroll the child view controller as well. That is, when dragging the child view controller vertically, I want the whole parent scroll view, including the child, to scroll vertically the same offset. But when dragging the child view controller horizontally, I just want to scroll the child view controller itself and keep its parent fixed. I'm still not able to achieve this behaviour, any help?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding tap gestures?

something like

Add tap gestures to the scroll views

Initially set `scrollDarkGrey.enabled = NO`

When the Dark grey `scrollView` is tapped `scrollDarkGrey.enabled =YES`

Then when parent scroll is tapped `scrollDarkGrey.enabled = NO`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height of your inner scrollView to the height of your parent scrollview's content.

Comment: Ah cleaner than my suggestion

Comment: I'm trying this: `CGSize sz = self.childScrollView.bounds.size;
    sz.height = self.parentScrollView.contentSize.height;
    sz.width = childWidth;
    self.horizontalScrollView.contentSize = sz;`, but it doesn't seem to work...